# Unable to enable Wifi on a Lenovo B570

Tags: 11.10, wireless, laptop

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop on my Windows 7 Laptop (Lenovo B570).

Wired connection works fine, but I'm not able to even switch wireless on.

As soon as I click the wireless button from off to on, it goes back to off automatically.

Tried looking online for answers, not able to find anything.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Just to know, when you say "I clicked it form off to on", do you mean marked the checkbox next to "Enable Wireless" in the "connection inidcator"?

Comment: What is the output from: **iwconfig**?

Answer (score 2):

add `blacklist acer_wmi` to your /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf , for example:

```
sudo -s
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop (b570) and had a difficult time. Hopefully you have dual boot with windows. In my case I had to blacklist acer-wmi in the document "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" (at the bottom type in "blacklist acer-wmi" without quotes) then reboot back into windows and turn on the wireless, reboot back into Ubuntu and it worked.

I had tried for days with just blacklisting, then messing with the hardware switch on the actual case, tried the fn key and most everything I could google with no luck. Then upon needing wireless booted into windows realized it was off there too, turned it on, back into Ubuntu 11.10 and fixed.